# Best practice to access application configuration from an Akka typed actor

Tags: akka

I would like to apologize for the really dumb question. I have tried to look for an answer in Google and Stack Overflow, but I do not seem to find what I am looking for.

I have spent this evening trying to write my first Actors using the Java DSL and Akka 2.6.4. Apart from the shocking verbosity of the framework and the massive use of inheritance, all good :) I can see why Scala is the language of choice for Akka.

That being said, I wanted to take the next step and start using Hazelcast in an Actor. The Hazelcast cluster runs as a separate service and I want to pass the ActorSystem the address of the cache so that actors can use it.

At which point I stopped and I asked myself, what is the right way to manage application configuration in Akka? I created a simple `application.conf` file that looks like:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
}

gateway {
    hazelcast.address = "localhost:5467"
}
```

and I pass the configuration to the `ActorSystem` as follows:

```
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
        ActorSystem<Event> system = ActorSystem.create(Gateway.create(), "gateway", config.getConfig("gateway"));
```

and all seems to work. Now my questions are:

- Is this the right place to store application specific configuration?
- If so, how do I access the `hazelcast.address` variable?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there was an error in the way configuration was fed to the `ActorSystem`:

```
ActorSystem<Event> system = ActorSystem.create(Gateway.create(), "gateway", config);
```

Secondly, to access the configuration, an actor can use the following *simple* statement:

```
String hazelcastAddress = context.getSystem().settings().config().getString("gateway.hazelcast.address");
```